# PHP five star rating - stars don't remain clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I have used the five star rating system(Based on jquery and PHP) provided [in this link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/) for one of my clients. Now, they want that if the user rates a product those many number of stars should remain highlighted but in the current scenario, once the user moves out his mouse the stars no longer remain highlighted.

I have tried a lot but the `mouseout` functions conflicts with the `click` function. So far, i'm using this :

**HTML**

```
 <div id="r1" class="rate_widget">
    <div class="star_1 ratings_stars" id="1"></div>
    <div class="star_2 ratings_stars" id="2"></div>
    <div class="star_3 ratings_stars" id="3"></div>
    <div class="star_4 ratings_stars" id="4"></div>
    <div class="star_5 ratings_stars" id="5"></div>
    <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
</div>
```

**JS** - I have tweaked this a bit on my own but to no success.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('.ratings_stars').hover(
        // Handles the mouseover
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        },
        // Handles the mouseout
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
            // can't use 'this' because it wont contain the updated data
            set_votes($(this).parent());
        }
    );
    
    
    // This actually records the vote
    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();
        count = $(star).attr('id');
        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
            'ratings.php',
            clicked_data,
            function(INFO) {
                widget.data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
//$(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
    //        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        $('#msg').hide().html("you have rated this product with "+count+" stars.").fadeIn(1500);
        //alert("you have rated this product with"+count);
            },
            'json'
        ); 
    });
    
    
    
});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);
    
    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
   // $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}
```

In the current situation, once the stars are clicked it shows the updated average rating returned from the PHP calculation script.

I want the stars to remain highlighted after clicked upon and even after `mouseout` and if they are not clicked the `mouseout` should function as it is i.e. unhighlight the stars.

Please help, i am desperate.

Comment: It sounds like something related to `CSS`

Comment: @MISJHA No, its JS only as it is handling the mouseout function in addition to the click function too.

Comment: Just a thought, wouldn't it be easier to change the "database" rating to a dif class, have that class(es) be the base to the each star element. Then use the hover classes strictly for hovering, finally when a user makes a selection, set a selected class that uses `!important` in its css to override all other applicable classes.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Can u elaborate a little more? Maybe a sample code to start with? PLEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its current setup, the `set_votes(widget)` method does not *know*, whether the user actually voted.
You can add this quite easily by modifying your 'click' event handler and adding a piece of data in your AJAX success callback:

```
...
function(INFO) {
    widget.data( 'fsr', INFO );
    // Add user's voting to data:
    widget.data('fsr').own_voting = count;

    set_votes(widget); 
    $('#msg').hide().html("you have rated this product with "+count+" stars.").fadeIn(1500);
    //alert("you have rated this product with"+count);
}
...
```

Then, you have to also modify the `set_votes(widget)` method to use this information:

```
function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    var own = $(widget).data('fsr').own_voting;

    // set voting to own if it is defined, else to avg
    // also set class to distinguish avg from own
    if(typeof own != 'undefined') {
        voting = own;
            class = 'ratings_over';
    } else {
        voting = avg;
            class = 'ratings_vote';
    }

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);

    // replaced avg with voting
    // remove all classes to make sure nothing bugs
    $(widget).find('.star_' + voting).nextAll()
             .removeClass('ratings_vote').removeClass('ratings_over');
    $(widget).find('.star_' + voting).prevAll().andSelf()
             .removeClass('ratings_vote').removeClass('ratings_over').addClass(class); 
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}
```

I'm not really familiar with JS, so the `undefined` part might be wrong - but AFAIK it should work like this.

---

If you want the widget to display the user's voting even after the page has been reloaded, you will have to add the `own_voting` field to your server's response to the fetching AJAX call.

Comment: i think i didnt explain well, the problem is that on the mouseout function, the stars become unhighlighted after the click is fired. your code is modifying set_votes which i think won't make any difference.

Comment: It does matter, because all the `mouseout` event handler does, is reset the widget's `ratings_over` classes, and call `set_votes(widget)`. The modified `set_votes(widget)` then either sets the widget to `avg` (if the user did never vote) or to the new `own` (if the user voted).